# "MouseEvent not defined " client side its not working in primeng angular 4?

Tags: angular, primeng-turbotable

In angular universal project turbo table is not working while running server side displaying error "MouseEvent" not defined

I have imported the turbo table module as given in the primeng website, but server side rendering

Comment: any success yet?